# android notification channel sound not working

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I know there has be a lot of post about the issue. I have tried them all. Here are the steps I did.

First I found out that once a channel has been created it can't be change. The only way was to reinstall the app. So that's what I did and it did not work.

Second, some say I can delete the channel so I also did that using this code

```
val channelList = mNotificationManager.notificationChannels
        var i = 0
        while (channelList != null && i < channelList.size) {
            Log.d("channelList","channel ID is ${channelList[i].id}")
            //mNotificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channelList[i].id)
            i++
        }
```

and then recreating the channel after deletion.

Third, I tried using a new notification channel but I kept getting an error every time I use the new channel.

Here is the code I am using with all those solution that I tried

```
 val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .build()


        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT

        val channelList = mNotificationManager.notificationChannels
        var i = 0
        while (channelList != null && i < channelList.size) {
            Log.d("channelList","channel ID is ${channelList[i].id}")
            mNotificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channelList[i].id)
            i++
        }

        Log.d("isnotification"," is it needed $isNotificationSoundNeeded importance is $importance")
        val mChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, appName,  NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        mChannel.setShowBadge(false)
        mChannel.setSound(notifSound, audioAttributes)



        val mChannelnew = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID2, appName,  NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        mChannelnew.setShowBadge(false)
        mChannelnew.setSound(notifSound, audioAttributes)




        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
```

What am I missing? Any ideas? Thanks

Update: here is the code for notifsound

```
val notifSound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.unconvinced)
```

Comment: Where is your code for creating the `notifSound` object? Note that uninstall/reinstalling the app does not reset your channels - you need to Clear Data on your app.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have updated my post

Comment: Which error are you receiving?

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai If I use a new channel I will get a broken channel error. If I use the original it works but it won't register any sound at all. It is so weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I do not know Your Notification is not working on which devices like **Oreo**, **Pie** or below than **N**.

`For your question StackOver Flow have lots of answer.`

Now As per your question Your missing only one line of code But here unable to check your whole notification code because of you are not pasted yet.

Here I am Pasting a Notification code which is just fulfill your all notification requirement. (**Full Custom Notification**)

***Notification With Image***

```
public void createNotificationWithImage(String title,String message ,Bitmap image) {
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
            0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Custom Sound Uri

Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sniper_gun);

 mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
 mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification_icon);

 // Pay attention on below line here (NOTE)
 mBuilder.setSound(soundUri);

if (image!=null) {
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setLargeIcon(image)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                            .bigPicture(image).setSummaryText(message).bigLargeIcon(null))
                    .setColor(Color.GREEN)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        }
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Now I am pasting code of notification which will work above or on **OREO** devices.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

        if(soundUri != null){
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .build();
            notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes);
        }

        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mNotificationManager.notify(0 /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());


below middle braces use for close your method.
}
```

**Notification for without Image**

```
    public void createNotification(String title,String message){
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
                0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sniper_gun);



        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification_icon);
        mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                R.mipmap.icon));
        mBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setColor(Color.GREEN)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
//            notificationChannel.s

            if(soundUri != null){
                AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                        .build();
                notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes);
            }

            assert mNotificationManager != null;
            mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }

        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mNotificationManager.notify(0 /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

**NOTE**: In my code I mentioned that pay attention on one specific line where I descrided about to set sound Uri with Notification. You can describe like this.

```
mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setColor(Color.GREEN)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

but it will not play a sound for your because after Oreo device is not set a sound as a priority level.

**So always for sound use code as I described.**

Comment: I had to change my Audio Attributes from the type of Notification to Alarm like in this post.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you are using the wrong usage type , please edit your `audioAttributes` usage to `USAGE_NOTIFICATION`

```
            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
            .build()
```

From the official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes) :

> USAGE_NOTIFICATION : 
>     Usage value to use when the usage is notification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use audio attributes and also need to define the ringtone URI with permission.

So first we define the ringtone URI:

```
Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
boolean vibrate = true;
long[] vibratePattern = new long[]{0L, 1000L};



public constructor(){
 notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, app.getAppContext().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id));
        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mContext.grantUriPermission("com.android.systemui", ringtoneUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}
 public void showNotificationNormal(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody, Intent intent) {
    String id = mContext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    PendingIntent lowIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, id);
    NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = mContext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name);
        String description = mContext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_description); //user visible
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.enableVibration(vibrate);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(vibratePattern);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        mChannel.setSound(ringtoneUri, att);
        mChannel.setBypassDnd(true);
        mChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        mChannel.setShowBadge(true);

        if (mNotifyManager != null) {
            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setVibrate(vibratePattern)
                .setSound(ringtoneUri)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationBody))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentIntent(lowIntent);

    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setVibrate(vibratePattern)
                .setSound(ringtoneUri)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationBody))
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentIntent(lowIntent);

    }

    notificationBuilder.setContentText(notificationBody);

    if (mNotifyManager != null) {
        mNotifyManager.notify(AppConstants.NOTIFY_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```